# Dash Plotly Cytoscape initial zoom isn't working

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I'm trying to create a Cytoscape on Plotly Dash. The zoom value I gave in Cytoscape props does not affect.

```
cyto.Cytoscape(
    id='my-cytoscape',
    zoom=500,
    layout={"name": "preset"},
    style={"width": "100%", "height": "600px"},
    stylesheet=[{
        "selector": "node",
        "style": {"width": "data(node_size)",
                  "height": "data(node_size)",
                  "label": "data(label)",
                  "backgroundColor": "blue",
                  "fontSize": "11px"},
    },
        {"selector": "edge",
         "style": {"width": 0.4, "curve-style": "bezier"}},
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `preset` layout sets `fit` to `True` by default ([source](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/e6541de603f5714f572238573ea06ef17503282b/src/extensions/layout/preset.js#L9)).

The documentation tells us the problem with this:

> Initial viewport state
> zoom : The initial zoom level of the graph. Make sure to disable viewport manipulation options, such as fit, in your layout so that it is not overridden when the layout is applied...

https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/e6541de603f5714f572238573ea06ef17503282b/documentation/md/core/init.md#initial-viewport-state

So you just need to set `fit` to `False` in your `Cytoscape` component's `layout` property:

```
layout = (
    {
        "name": "preset",
        "fit": False,
    },
)
```

---

Also your zoom level was too zoomed in for me when I tested it.

Minimal fully reproducible example:

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        cyto.Cytoscape(
            id="cytoscape-two-nodes",
            zoom=5,
            style={"width": "100%", "height": "600px"},
            layout={
                "name": "preset",
                "fit": False,
            },
            elements=[
                {
                    "data": {"id": "one", "label": "Node 1"},
                    "position": {"x": 75, "y": 75},
                },
                {
                    "data": {"id": "two", "label": "Node 2"},
                    "position": {"x": 200, "y": 200},
                },
                {"data": {"source": "one", "target": "two"}},
            ],
        )
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am working with approximately 200 nodes whose coordinates are given specifically. The cytoscape looked very small because the distance between some nodes was too high. Your answer helped, thanks.